# Download images and show them in a slideshow

Tags: ios, download, uiimageview

For the slideshow feature, the images are on a remote server, then can we implement a batch look ahead download of the images? We want say 'n' images ahead downloaded when an image is being viewed - this helps in providing a smoother viewing experience. Is this a good way to get zero latency for the slideshow or is there any better way than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide a smooth viewing experience as well as reduce (not zeroing) the latency for your slide show, I agree with caching mechanism.

I assume that you have a list of image urls, now as soon as the slide show displaying on the screen, start loading visible items. Trigger scroll view did scroll and load in the background the next n images after the last visible index, then cache them. So that whenever user scrolling to next indexes, images almost the time will be there in your memory and displayed instantly.

Why we should trigger scroll view did scroll. Firstly, because that is the idle time that allows you start doing things without user's notice. Secondly, if you start loading images while scrolling, at the time it is set to UIImageView, your slide show will be lag due to that task executed on main thread.

As the answer above, SDWebImage is a good library that can help you finish your task.
By the way, if you will consider of using SDWebImage, I would suggest you config this option

```
/**
     * By default, image downloads are started during UI interactions, this flags disable this feature,
     * leading to delayed download on UIScrollView deceleration for instance.
     */
    SDWebImageLowPriority = 1 << 1,
```

I hope my answer will contribute 2 cents to solve your problem.

Comment: Why to enable *SDWebImageLowPriority* flag? It delays the download.

Answer (score 0):

In my opninion, use `SDWebImage` https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage to preload images and clean memory cache if if exceed memory-limit.